# Firebase endpoint executes wrong function

Tags: python, firebase, google-cloud-functions

This is really bizarre.

I have two endpoints, `stream` and `similar_movies`. They each deploy to `https://stream-<unique id>-uc.a.run.app` and `https://similar-movies-<unique id>-uc.a.run.app`, respectively. However, when I access the `stream` endpoint with a `query` param, I get the error below in the function for the *other endpoint*.

Am I doing something wrong to cause this? I fixed this once by deleting the endpoints in the Firebase console and re-creating them, and everything worked dandy, but that solution is no longer solving the problem.

```
@https_fn.on_request(cors=options.CorsOptions(
        cors_origins=[r"http://localhost:3000", r"http://127.0.0.1:8080", r"https://<project id>.web.app"],
        cors_methods=["get", "post"],
    ),
)
def stream(req: https_fn.Request) -> https_fn.Response:
    query = req.args.get('query')
    prompt = SEARCH_PROMPT_TEMPLATE % query
    return Response(stream_with_context(_gpt_streaming(prompt, prefix='search')), content_type='text/plain')


@https_fn.on_request(cors=options.CorsOptions(
        cors_origins=[r"http://localhost:3000", r"http://127.0.0.1:8080", r"https://<project id>.web.app"],
        cors_methods=["get", "post"],
    ),
)

def similar_movies(req: https_fn.Request) -> https_fn.Response:
    raw_titles = req.args.get('titles')
    titles = [urllib.parse.unquote(title) for title in raw_titles.split(',')]
    prompt = SIMILAR_MOVIES_PROMPT_TEMPLATE % '\n'.join(titles)
    return Response(stream_with_context(_gpt_streaming(prompt, prefix='similar-movies')), content_type='text/plain')
```

```
DEFAULT 2023-09-18T15:16:09.546038Z File "/workspace/main.py", line 173, in similar_movies
DEFAULT 2023-09-18T15:16:09.546042Z titles = [urllib.parse.unquote(title) for title in raw_titles.split(',')]
DEFAULT 2023-09-18T15:16:09.546046Z ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
DEFAULT 2023-09-18T15:16:10.585588Z AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'
```

Comment: I fixed this by renaming `stream` to `search` and redeploying, which fixed that function, but broke the other one.